# Joining queries in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to join these 2 tables

- Table 1: wp_usermeta, where I am storing my users' last logged in time
- Table 2: wp_chats, where am storing chats between users

This query grabs the logged in user and counts the chats from that user to the current user. However it will not return a logged in user if there are no chats from that user.

How can I make this query return all logged in users even when there are no chats?

```
SELECT m.user_id, COUNT(c.from_id) as cnt 
FROM wp_chats c 
JOIN wp_usermeta m  ON  m.user_id=c.from_id
WHERE m.meta_key='user_last_login' 
 AND m.meta_value>=$time 
 AND c.to_id=$from_id 
 AND c.received=0 
GROUP BY c.from_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edc6b/1

Users 2,3,4,5,6 are all logged in and should be in the output. User 7 in not logged in and does not appear.

Only 3, 6 are showing up however. How can i get all but #7 to be in the output?

Comment: check out the fiddle and the comments above http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edc6b/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** perfected query in fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edc6b/12

```
SELECT m.user_id, COUNT(c.from_id) as cnt 
FROM wp_usermeta m
LEFT JOIN wp_chats c   
  ON  m.user_id=c.from_id
  AND c.received=0
  AND c.to_id=2
WHERE m.meta_key='user_last_login' 
AND m.meta_value>=1347305273               
GROUP BY m.user_id;
```

Comment: Based on the info provided, a left join should be your answer. Perhaps if you create a sql fidde, http://sqlfiddle.com/ I could be of better help.

Comment: the query is within a $wpdb->get_results($q); could that be affecting it?

Comment: @cheezlaweez, nope, wrote it out wrong, the userMeta table needs to be first and left join in the chats table to that. Also, any filtering to the chats table needs to be done in the on clause. I edited my answer to be the query you need.